# php mysql fetch the record without while or foreach

Tags: php, mysql

i have something to solve.
i have this code but i can't use while and im not sure for foreach.
i dont know how to use foreach...

i have 3 records in the database. now i want to pull it out the email
example below { database email store }

```
id email
1  coco@gmail.com
2  mama@yahoo.com
3  lala@coco.com
```

now i have this insert query
this insert query have this diff email

database sample below { database list email store }

```
id email_1 email_2 email_3 email_4 bla bla
```

how can i pull out the email store and `put it to my list email` store in `ONE ID`

```
mysql_query( "INSERT INTO listEmail VALUE( '', 'email_1', 'email_2', 'email_3' ....)" )
```

thank you guys...

Comment: from what I understood, you want to know how to pull the records from database?

Comment: yes like i want to put it in the array

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to fetch the results from a table

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tableName");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
   $values[] = $row['email'];

 }
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($values);
 echo "</pre>";
```

Go here :) http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net is the best place to look for: check in particular this page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

I think you need the basics first, as your question is very unclear.